# how to loop through rows of data in one sheet and populate the same in every sheets of a specific cell in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

MY excel has multiple worksheets and i want to loop through data of every rows of column B and Column C  from master sheet and i want each row/ cell  value to be reflected in each worksheets i have in a particular cell in order. My mastersheet name is comments where i want to loop through every rows of value located in column B". but my every worksheets tabs in cell A1 is giving me the last value of the mastersheet row cell value
[my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S42f1.jpg)
[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FZ7W.png)

```
Sub vba_loop_sheets()

Dim i As Long
Dim shtcount As Long
Dim cell As Range
shtcount = Sheets.Count

For i = 2 To shtcount 'i want the data to be reflected from 2nd worksheet hence started from 2"
    For Each cell In Sheets("comments").Range("B1:B7") 
        Sheets(i).Range("A1").Value = cell.Value
    Next cell
Next i

End Sub
```

the above code is giving me only the last row value from mastersheet after looping and in every worksheets i have only the last value. But i want my mastersheets values to be reflected in order in every worksheets tabs

Comment: `Sheets(i).Range(cell.address).Value = cell.Value`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Sub vba_loop_sheets()

Dim i As Long
Dim shtcount As Long
Dim cell As Range
shtcount = Sheets.Count

For i = 2 To shtcount 'i want the data to be reflected from 2nd worksheet hence started from 2"
    Sheets(i).Range("A1:A7").Value = Sheets("comments").Range("B1:B7") 
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub vba_loop()
Dim i As Long
Dim shtcount As Long
shtcount = Sheets.Count
For i = 2 To shtcount
Sheets(i).Range("A1").Value = Sheets("comments").Range("B1:B7").Value 

Next i

End Sub
```

the above code is giving me only the first value of B1 cell from comments sheets to every sheets. however i want B1,B2,B3....values to be reflected in sheet1 A1 cell,sheet2 A1 cell,sheet3 A1 cell...sorry if i wasn't clear on my first question.

Comment: `Sheets(i).Range("A1").Value = Sheets("comments").Range("B1").offset(i-2).Value`

Comment: perfect it is working thanks a lot much needed help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).